# Execute PHP file

Tags: php

Alright this probably sounds easier than it is :)

I've got two files:

```
file1.php
file2.php
```

Withing my `file1.php` is a loop and within that loop i'd like to execute (not include) `file2.php`.

```
while(1){ //execute file2.php }
```

I know i could use `exec()` or wrap `file2.php` into a function but is there a native function to do something like this?

Comment: Why do you want php to execute php?

Comment: i need to quickly develop a testing environment and this is the most realistic approach to simulate something :)

Comment: `include` will execute the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) should do the trick.

Comment: NO. use `require` or `include`.

Comment: @maček OP specifically said not to use include, so I just listened. I'd say your -1 isn't justified.

Comment: (although I may agree Palantir's answer is a better solution)

Answer (score 4):

And why shouldn't an "include()" work?

If you need, you could perform some ambient sanitization or initialization before. If you included the file in a function's body, for example, all the local variables would be masked. You'd still need to move session contents, for example, but that's easy...

Otherwise, you could still launch the php interpreter (exec php passing it the script as argument). It's easier to make a wrapper bash script for that.

Answer (score 1):

If really necessary, you can use **[backticks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)**. E.g.:

```
$output = `php file2.php`;
```

---

But I would encapsulate the functionality in `file2.php` in a function, include the file once and run this function in your loop. This is a much cleaner approach imho.

Comment: thanks, didn't even know there is anything like that in php :)

Comment: why wouldn't you use `require` or `include`?

Comment: @maček: The OP explicitly stated to **not** include the file. `include`ing would load all the symbols of that file into the file where it is included to, which might cause collisions and what not. Calling `php file2.php` seemed to be a really easy way to still execute the file and avoid those problems. But I also mentioned that with proper structure of the file, an `include` would be a more appropriate solution.